# Operations within same row group with repetitions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to subtract each *row group* (**ID**) according to the following:

1) *group data* by **ID** and *order* it by **Order**

2) **subtract "C2"** to each element of the group

data:

```
df <- data.frame (ID=rep(c("F1","F2","F3","F4","F5"),c(5,3,6,2,4)),
              Cond=rep(c("C1","C2","C3","C4"),5),
              Value=c(1:20),
          Y_REAL = c(-1,0,1,2,3,
                      0,1,2,
                     -1,0,1,2,3,4,
                      NA,NA,
                      -1,0,1,2))

Order     <- c("C1","C2","C3","C4")# order to be sorted the elements
```

I am written the code below ... but something is not working well

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
Out <-  df  %>% #filter(Wheat_Exp,Field=="2014_P1") %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
slice(match(Order,Cond))%>% 
mutate(Y_Diff = Value - lag(Value, default = Value[Cond == "C2"]))
```

(updated)

The column **Y_Diff** subtracts the output in relation to the first element of the group (**ID**). Not correct! 
The column **Y_REAL** is the output I would like to obtain.
Additionally, 3 rows are "lost" along the computation.

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: @Ronan done 
Axeman, I have tried your suggestion but it does not work. nonetheless...I have incorporated in the question, since I believe it is easier to understand my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `ifelse` to guard against "empty" groups, and use `which.max` to find the first `Value` for which `Cond == 'C2'`. Then do the simple subtraction:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Y_diff = Value - ifelse('C2' %in% Cond, Value[which.max(Cond == 'C2')], NA))
```

> ```
> Source: local data frame [20 x 5]
> Groups: ID [5]
>
>        ID   Cond Value Y_REAL Y_diff
>    <fctr> <fctr> <int>  <dbl>  <int>
> 1      F1     C1     1     -1     -1
> 2      F1     C2     2      0      0
> 3      F1     C3     3      1      1
> 4      F1     C4     4      2      2
> 5      F1     C1     5      3      3
> 6      F2     C2     6      0      0
> 7      F2     C3     7      1      1
> 8      F2     C4     8      2      2
> 9      F3     C1     9     -1     -1
> 10     F3     C2    10      0      0
> 11     F3     C3    11      1      1
> 12     F3     C4    12      2      2
> 13     F3     C1    13      3      3
> 14     F3     C2    14      4      4
> 15     F4     C3    15     NA     NA
> 16     F4     C4    16     NA     NA
> 17     F5     C1    17     -1     -1
> 18     F5     C2    18      0      0
> 19     F5     C3    19      1      1
> 20     F5     C4    20      2      2
> ```